# Input informativo, como fazer?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Boa tarde pessoal! Eu estou fazendo um formulário informativo com o Framework Bootstrap, onde em alguns campos deverão aparecer um balãozinho informativo em cima do campo (tipo [um balão de diálogo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bal%C3%A3o_de_di%C3%A1logo)), informando ao usuário como ele deve preencher o campo. Mais só que eu não faço a menor ideia de como isso é feito. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: de uma pesquisada sobre `jquery.validate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o próprio `bootstrap` com o recurso de `tooltips`.

Documentação: [**ToolTips**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

Você só precisa aplicar os atributos `data-toggle` na tag input com o valor tooltip, um `data-placement` que é a posição do tooltip (top, bottom, left, right), um `data-trigger` que é como o tooltip é acionado (focus, hover, etc) e definir um `title` que é o texto que será exibido no tooltip.

**OBS:** Tudo isso é explicado detalhadamente na documentação.

Exemplo:

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <label for="name">Seu nome:</label>
            <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom" title="Minha dica legal" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: É exatamente isto que eu estava procurando @Learne, modifiquei o meu html aqui e funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado pela força! Abraço.